# Why does "std::cout << myVector[x][x] << std::endl" produce a subscript error?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

This is probably a very simple question, however it is hounding me. 
I can get the data into the container but I can't then seem to print it to the console.

The following produces a subscript out of range debug error

Here is my code

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> myVector;

for (int x = 0; x != 18; x++)
{
   myVector.push_back(std::vector<int>(x,x));
   std::cout << myVector[x][x] << std::endl;
}
```

Many thanks!

Comment: Indices in C++ are zero-based. You put `x` elements into the vector, but you’re attempting to access the `x+1`st element.

Comment: In other words, it's telling you it's out of range because it is (errors are useful!). I'll also add that most popular programming languages have 0-based indexes.

Answer (score 2):

When you do `std::vector<int>(x,x)` inside for loop when `x=0` you allocate `zero elements`. At other times you allocate `x` elements(row index:`x` and column indexes: `0,1,...x-1`) and access `x+1`th element in `x`th row.

So change it to

```
for (int x = 0; x != 18; x++)
{
  myVector.push_back(vector<int>(x+1,x));
  std::cout << myVector[x][x] << std::endl;
}
```